# How to create multipart form data request for image and json data using URLSession- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, file-upload, multipartform-data

I need to send an image and json data to the server by using `multipart/form-data` request by using URLSession. Please refer the below screenshot for request.

[image]

I can successfully able to upload the image and json data by using postman. But i am struggling to upload the image and json data by using URLSession

Please refer to the below code

```
    let session = URLSession.shared        
    let boundary = UUID().uuidString
    
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://dev.example.com/api/msg/sendmsg")!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.setValue(authToken, forHTTPHeaderField: Key.RequestParam.authToken)
    
    urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    var data = Data()
    
    data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    
    let imageName = "file"
    data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(imageName)\"; filename=\"\(imageName)\" \r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    data.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg \r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    data.append(imageData)
    
    data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    
    data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=msgRequest \r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    data.append("Content-Type: application/json \r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    data.append(msgRequest)
    
    data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    
    urlRequest.httpBody = data
    
    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { responseData, response, error in
        if(error != nil){
            print("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        guard let responseData = responseData else {
            print("no response data")
            return
        }
        if let responseString = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("uploaded to: \(responseString)")
        }
    }.resume()
```

Request headers

```
["Authorization": "Bearer edasdasddaUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdaaddjY0OCIsImRldmljZUlkIjoiNEI4OTEzREYtQTQyQSEJBmlkcuwWF0IjoxNjcyNzM5NzY1LCasdadadasjk1NjV9.eaddLFCRK0mMICuFhhujhdoaise3M-RiydXoiuhowbfs", "Content-Length": "11314616", "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=08D6DB1A-C888-40E5-8BD6-FE218E892A06"]
```

Below is the urlRequest data

```
--08D6DB1A-C888-40E5-8BD6-FE218E892A06

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file1"

Content-Type: "image/jpeg"

ImageData

--08D6DB1A-C888-40E5-8BD6-FE218E892A06

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="msgRequest"

Content-Type: "application/json"

{"msgBody":"Hi there”,”clientId”:”29385422222”}

--08D6DB1A-C888-40E5-8BD6-FE218E892A06--
```

I am getting the response `Status Code: 400`

Please help me out with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering : I see a space after `name=`: `name= msgRequest` and `name= \"\(imageName)\"`, and also in `filename`. Is `msgRequest` correct JSON?

Comment: @Larme Fixed the extra space issue but still got the same response. and for msgRequest, I am using the codable protocol to encode the model. so I hope it's correct.

Comment: 400 error code means that something wrong with your request. Try to add breakpoint before `session.dataTask(with: urlRequest)` and check status of your `urlRequest`. Looks like some value in it is wrong or absent. For example you can add `print(urlRequest)`

Comment: @ВолодимирUkraine I have added the urlRequest data above.

Comment: @Shubham in the screen from postman there are 8 headers.  You request does not contain all of them. That's why I asked to print and check `urlRequest` instead of `urlRequest.data`. Or you can duplicate you request in postmen and delete unnecessary headers and test it again. But right now you urlRequest do not equal your request in postman, that's the reason.

Comment: @ВолодимирUkraine I have updated the request headers above. After removing unnecessary headers from postman all other headers I am already sending in the request headers.